# Python Django duplicate loop

Tags: python, django, loops, for-loop, django-models

i fetch two table from my db like this:

```
query_tags = Tags.objects.all()
query_usertags = UserNews.objects.all()

context = {'query_tags': query_tags, 'query_utags': query_usertags}
```

and in my html , i try that:

```
   {% for tags in query_tags %}
        {% for utags in query_utags %}

            {% if utags.user_tag == tags.name and utags.userid == user.id %}

            <input disabled type="checkbox" id="development" value={{ tags.name }} name="user_interest">
            <label class="light" for="development">{{ tags.name }}</label><br>
            {% else %}
                <input  type="checkbox" id="development" value={{ tags.name }} name="user_interest">
            <label class="light" for="development">{{ tags.name }}</label><br>

            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
```

but my problem is output gonna duplicated cuz of second loop
can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the associations between Tags and UserNews in your view and set up a structure that can be queried from your template. Sorry, it is hard to tell what the relationship is between those two objects based on the code you posted, either logical or in your Django models. Also worth examining why you don't have a formal relationship between your models if one exists and you want to query it.

Comment: can u help me to associations in view ? and if i use relationships , my problem gonna fix?

Comment: Just move the logic (for loops, if statement) into your view, and create a dict with Tags as keys and UserKey lists as values. Making the relationship formal can help you:
- drop the if statement
- not query all child objects
- document your models better